# File attachment from HTML form doesn't get replaced on Domino server

Tags: file-upload, lotus-domino

I have a Domino database that stores documents with file attachments. The file attachments are stored in the `Body` RichTextItem as attachments.

For managing these documents I have an HTML form containing a file upload field.

Now, when I upload a file whose name differs from the current file in the document, everything works fine, and the uploaded attachment replaces the previous attachment.

The problem is when I upload a file that has the same name as the already existing file. In the `WebQuerySave` property of the form I call a LotusScript agent that should replace the old attachment with the one from the HTML form.

But in this agent I see two items called `$FILE` that have the same `FileName`. When I access them, I cannot distinguish these two items. I tried:

- `document.GetAttachment(filename)` – obviously doesn't work, since the names are the same => I can only access the first attachment.
- `ForAll item in document.Items` – I visit two items having the name `$FILE`, but both items are *the same*: the modification time is the same, the filesize is the same.

I could get all the attachments and remove all of them but the last. But is there any guarantee that the last item is the one from the HTML form? Or I could first extract the modification time from all the attachments and remember the newest. That must be the attachment from the HTML form.

Or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

For reasons like this behavior and several others, I have built most of the basic web facing Domino applications to store attachments on linked documents instead of the primary document. That way they can be accessed easily and do not get updated or modified except when they are supposed to be.

Comment: That's a good advice in general. In my situation it doesn't apply though, since I inherited a large code base which I don't dare to change in that large ways. Especially since I only understand some small parts of Domino.

Comment: Then you will most likely not find a workaround as the behavior you describe is the expected behavior.